# Play remote sound using QT

Tags: qt, audio

My requirement is capture sounds from a machine and send the sound buffer instantaneously through a channel, So that I can play the sound in remote machine simultaneously. I have to develop it in QT framework. I am new to QT framework.

Is it possible with available QT classes(QAudioDeviceInfo, QAudioInput, QAudioOutput and  Phonon etc.,)

If it is possible please share some sample code which will help me a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see the spectrum analyser example given by qt

http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2010/05/18/qtmultimedia-in-action-a-spectrum-analyser

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/demos-spectrum.html

Comment: I saw QTMobilty is related to capture the audio and play it. Will it be useful in my case. Do i need to select QTMultimedia or can I select QTMobilty. Please suggest me on that

Comment: Thanks shobi.  Can you please tell me differences between QtMultimedia and QTMobilty (or disadvantages of QT Mobility over QtMultimedia)

Comment: QtMultimedia is a qt library used to handle all the multimedia apps... and QtMobility is basically for mobile aaplications... check this.. http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.0-tp/